# How often is while(true) called in C# Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, while-loop

How often is while(true) called in C# Unity? Is it like Update(), where it's called every frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will recurse infinity in a single frame unless there is a break or yield (coroutine). With a coroutine if you do something like

```
yield return null;
```

it will continue the next frame.

Answer (score 1):

It will keep going within one frame drawing out the frame time to infinity. Unbroken, it will crash the editor or, if in a full build, the game.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is *once* ... the frame where while(true) is entered, assuming it has no break/return or other mechanism to stop it, will be the *last* frame before Unity crashes to your desktop, probably with no warning or error message.

I've crashed Unity before with accidental recursion, like writing `public int Number => Number;` instead of `public int Number => number;` (property that returns itself to itself infinitely) and Unity just crashes, silently. And it can be hard to find something like that after you've copied and pasted some code around. Infinite loops/recursion are basically fatal to Unity on the main thread.

You probably picked up that while(true) idea from a scripting language for a much simpler game engine where it handles a lot of stuff behind the scenes for you. I've seen it before in "3D Game Studio" engine, many, many years ago, in their "Lite C" scripting language. You'd simply put `while(1)` and it would run an iteration of your script loop on each frame and shut it down for you when it ended, very conveniently. But you can't do that in C#. Even though Unity calls it "scripting", C# is still a compiled programming language and it does exactly what you tell it to do. And while(true) is telling it "Repeat this loop until *true* is no longer *true*" (which means forever), so the loop never ends (unless you use break, return or something else to explicitly stop it).